# bind dynamically to this vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hey guys I have the following function its working ok but I think it could be better.

```
 methods: {
        onFileChange(e, filedName) {
            console.log(e.target.files);
            console.log(filedName);
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      const fileToCheck=document.getElementById(filedName);
      console.log(fileToCheck);
      if(filedName=='thumbnail1'){
          if(fileToCheck.value!=''){
            this.thumbnail1 = fileToCheck;
     this.thumbnail1Url= URL.createObjectURL(file);
     } else {
         this.thumbnail1=null;
         this.thumbnail1Url=null;
         }
     }
     if(filedName=='thumbnail2'){
         if(fileToCheck.value!=''){
             console.log(fileToCheck);
             this.thumbnail2=fileToCheck;
         this.thumbnail2Url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
         } else {this.thumbnail2=fileToCheck; this.thumbnail2Url=null;}
     }
    },
```

Instead of checking the value for

```
if(fieldName == "something"){
 this.something = URL.createObjectURL(file) 
}
```

I would simply pass in a string of the fieldName and bind to it dynamically by just typing `this.fieldName` (filedName could equal thumbnail1 or thumbnail2 or chicken for all I care I just want to be able to pass in the name of the data atrribute and bind to it that way) but when ever I do this it doesn't work. Any help here would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me what you want to accomplish, but I think you're asking about creating a dynamic data property for a view component. If that's the case, there are a couple of things to consider.

First, the example you cite, `this.fieldName` is not correct JavaScript syntax if `fieldName` is a string that contains a property name. The correct version is `this[fieldName]`.

Note, though, that you can't simply define a *new* data property for a Vue component by setting it to a value. That's a limitation of JavaScript that's described in the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). If `data[fieldName]` is an existing property that's defined in the component's `data` object, then you'll be okay. Even if you don't know the value of the property, you can initialize it, for example, with a value of `null` and then update the value in your method. Otherwise, you'll need to add the property to an existing non-root-level property as the documentation explains.